# Can I Use Google Apps Script to Get the List Preset From One Paragraph and Apply it to Another in Google Slides

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides

I'm trying to write some code in apps script to pull text from a text box in google slides and split it by paragraphs into new text boxes and I'm hitting a snag when I get to preserving lists. I haven't been successful in finding a simple way to get the [listPreset](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/list-preset) from the paragraphs in the original text box to the paragraphs in their own text boxes.

I was able to use [ListStyle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/list-style) methods [getGlyph()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/list-style#getGlyph()) and [isInList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/list-style#isInList()) successfully but unless I make a dictionary of which listPreset each glyph is in, I don't seem to able to retrieve the listPreset with any of the listed methods which I would need in order to fill into [applyListPreset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/list-style#applyListPreset(ListPreset)).

I'd love a getListPreset() function so I could just nab that from the original list. Is there something like that I'm missing?

[Here is an example "before" condition.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlj5N.png)

[Here is an example of the expected "after" condition.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lffzn.png)

[Here is an example of what the "after" condition is when I am unable to duplicate the listStyle from the original text box into the new text boxes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyA7A.png)

In the following example I copy the text from the original textbox and gather various attributes from it. I attempt to input the listStyle() information into the applyListPreset() method even though I know that's wrong. I just don't know how else to get the List Preset from the original text box.

FYI I've already had a bit of help with this already so it's not all my work.

```
function myFunction() { // get slides in the presentation
    var slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
    var numberOfLogs = 5;

    for (let slide of slides) { // get the objects on each slide
      splitParagraphs(slide);
    }
}

function splitParagraphs(slide){
  slideShapes = slide.getShapes();
  for(let shape of slideShapes){
      var shapetype = shape.getShapeType();
      if (shapetype == "TEXT_BOX"){ // checks to see if the object is a text box
        createSplitShapes(shape, slide);
        shape.remove();
      }
  }
}

function createSplitShapes(shape, slide){
  var paragraphs = shape.getText().getParagraphs();
  var oldHeight = shape.getHeight();
  var width = shape.getWidth();
  var newShapeHeight = oldHeight / paragraphs.length;

  for (let [index, paragraph] of paragraphs.entries() ){ // make a textbox for each paragraph distributed vertically over the original textbox
    createParagraphShapes(shape, index, paragraph, newShapeHeight, width, slide);
  }
}

function createParagraphShapes(shape, index, paragraph, shapeheight, width, slide){
  var text = paragraph.getRange();
  var list = text.getListStyle().isInList();
  var style = text.getListStyle();
  var glyph = text.getListStyle().getGlyph();
  var rawText = text.asString();
  var textStyle = text.getTextStyle();
  var fontsize = textStyle.getFontSize();
  var fontfamily = textStyle.getFontFamily();
  var fontweight = textStyle.getFontWeight();
  var paragraphStyle = text.getParagraphStyle();
  var alignment = paragraphStyle.getParagraphAlignment();
  var lineSpacing = paragraphStyle.getLineSpacing();
  var indent = paragraphStyle.getIndentStart();
  var shapetop = shapeheight * index + shape.getTop(); 

  if ( ! isBlank(rawText) ) {

    var t = slide.insertTextBox(rawText);

    t.setLeft(shape.getLeft());
    t.setTop(shapetop);
    t.setWidth(width);
    var newTextStyle = t.getText().getTextStyle();
    newTextStyle.setFontSize(fontsize);
    newTextStyle.setFontFamilyAndWeight(fontfamily, fontweight);
    var newParagraphStyle = t.getText().getParagraphStyle();
    newParagraphStyle.setParagraphAlignment(alignment);
    newParagraphStyle.setLineSpacing(lineSpacing);
    newParagraphStyle.setIndentStart(indent);

    if (list = true) {
      t.getText().getListStyle().applyListPreset(style);
    }

  }
}


function paragraphLogs(paragraph, numberOfLogs){
  if(numberOfLogs > 0){
    console.log("\tWhat's in paragraphs?: ");
    for (var k = 0; k < paragraph.length; k++){
      console.log("\t\t" + ( paragraphs[k].getRange().asString() )  );
    }
  }
}

function isBlank(str){
  return (!str || str.trim().length === 0);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code as well as expected results if possible.

Comment: @JasonE. I have included the code from our project. I was worried it would confuse things.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your issue. So, can you provide your sample input and output situations, that you expect, as the images? And also, can you provide the sample current situation as an image? By this, I would like to try to understand about your question.

Comment: @Tanaike I have added screenshots of the example situations. What the slide looks like, what the slide should look like, and what the slide looks like when my code currently runs without the solution I'm looking for.